# Elastic range input

Tags: css

How do I make the CSS for the bars on the right to move to the edge?

[**Link to my codepen snippet**](https://codepen.io/lmgonzalves/pen/NyzKdr)

```
.range__marks__pink {
    stroke: #FF4B81;
   }

.range__marks__white {
   stroke: white;
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: floating right not working...and right 0